# Why does ADBannerView show up strangely between devices in my Cocos2D V3 RC1 project?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, iad, adbannerview

I create my AdBannerView like this:

```
adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
adBannerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
adBannerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
CGSize sizeToFit = [adBannerView sizeThatFits:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view].frame.size];
[adBannerView setFrame:CGRectMake(([[CCDirector sharedDirector] view].frame.size.width - sizeToFit.width)/2.0f, 0, sizeToFit.width, sizeToFit.height)];
adBannerView.delegate = self;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:adBannerView];
```

The problem is that, while the view shows up properly on iPhone devices:

[image]

...the ads just look plain strange on iPad devices, like as if they are clipped at different points:

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: this happened only in simulator right ? if yes then ignore :)

Comment: @Guru Yeah, just in the simulator.

Comment: even I got same in simulator and game went live and working great now.